# Google Apps Script - setvalues not working on sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

OK so I seem to be stumped by setValue() and setValues()
I understand what they are, but can't get it to work.  No values appear to be set!
(This is part of a bigger script project to generate Invoices and Schedules from Google Calendar.)

```js
function Version3() {
// STEPXX - First create a copy of the template
// Choose the source
var RHTemplate = 'MY SHEET ID'
var RHCode = "HirerCode"
// Use the variable for the Billing Prefix as it should be unique to create the folder.
var RHFolder = DriveApp.createFolder("BillPrefix").getId()
var RHFolderID = DriveApp.getFolderById(RHFolder);
// Now copy the template file
var RHgetTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById(RHTemplate);
// var RHFileName = (SpreadsheetApp.openById(RHTemplate).rename(RHCode));
var RHFile = RHgetTemplate.makeCopy(RHCode, RHFolderID);
var RHss = SpreadsheetApp.open(RHFile);
var RHsheetInv = RHss.getSheetByName('Invoice') //.getSheets()[0]; get by sheet index
var RHCell = RHsheetInv.getRange(1, 1);
RHCell.setValues([RHCode]);
debugger
}
```

I just can't see why it's not writing the words "Hirer Code" in the first cell on the sheet called "Invoice" in the spreadsheet called "Hirer Code" in the folder called "BillPrefix".

Any and all help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For others having these issues I finally tied it down to an anomaly in debugging. When you run as debug, SOMETIMES it can setValue/setValues, sometimes it fails. It runs without issue however when you just run the function as normal. Similar issues with user interface pop up boxes!

Answer (score 2):

If it's a single value you are setting you do not need to worry about arrays. Use setValue() without the s.

Replace:

```
var RHCell = RHsheetInv.getRange(1, 1);
RHCell.setValues([RHCode]);
```

with:

```
RHsheetInv.getRange(1, 1).setValue(RHCode);
```

Comment: This worked.  Although I'd been playing with setValue and setValues and conflated my mistake!
However the issue appears to be permissions related.  In the past I was using setValues to the sheet which the script was run in.  This version however was supposed to be launched from a sheet which holds the search criteria and generates a new sheet.
When I took the script and ran it from http://script.google.com/ directly it worked fine so will now go research this!

Comment: Well, I thought it was working but it's stopped again!...
I've tried your solution and no joy :(

Comment: For others having these issues I finally tied it down to an anomaly in debugging.
When you run as debug, SOMETIMES it can setValue/setValues, sometimes it fails.  It runs without issue however when you just run the function as normal.
Similar issues with user interface pop up boxes!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably one of dimensionality. Set values deals with a 2-dimensional array. Your example provides a 1-dimensional array.

Original:

```
var RHCell = RHsheetInv.getRange(1, 1);
RHCell.setValues([RHCode]);
```

Corrected:

```
var RHCell = RHsheetInv.getRange(1, 1);
RHCell.setValues([ [ RHCode ] ]);
```

Comment: I've tried your solution and no joy :(
The fact neither setValue, or setValues works make me thing it's something else earlier...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that setValues() works asynchronously when in debug mode, because when you stop the code the values are written to the sheet.

Comment: Well, it works asynchronously in any mode since writing operation is slow and in some cases it might take significant time to perform. Thus, if you want to write a value and then use it anywhere else you should create a variable with this value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setFormula` method.

For example:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange(1, 7); //get the cell here
range.setFormula('"'+myValueHere+'"');
```